# SQLite: Select fields that contain at least one uppercase character

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

How do you select a field that contains at least one uppercase character in SQLite, or inversely, a field that doesn't contain any uppercase characters i.e. all lowercase chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a row with a column that has only uppercase in SQL could be done like this:

```
SELECT TargetCol FROM MyTable
WHERE UPPER(TargetCol) = TargetCol;
```

Since this is the inverse of 1 or more lowercase, like you said, this could be done like this:

```
SELECT TargetCol FROM MyTable
WHERE UPPER(TargetCol) != TargetCol;
```

For the opposite of this, you can use LOWER()